# Refactoring: Move (F6) in CLion - why does it work like that?

Tags: c++, refactoring, header-files, clion, automated-refactoring

I have in my main.cpp this function:

```
double median(double values[], int count) {
    int i, j, n = count, t;
    for (i = 1 ; i <= n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1 ; j <= n - i ; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] <= values[j + 1])
            {
                t = (int) values[j];
                values[j] = values[j + 1];
                values[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( n % 2 == 0)
        return (values[n / 2] + values[n / 2 + 1]) / 2.0 ;
    else
        return values[n / 2 + 1];
}
```

and I want to move that function into another file. So, I click on this function and then click F6 and then I write some name of the file eg. `MathFunctions` and then I end up with:

MathFunctions.h:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_NAME_MATHFUNCTIONS_H
#define PROJECT_NAME_MATHFUNCTIONS_H

#endif //PROJECT_NAME_MATHFUNCTIONS_H
```

MathFunctions.cpp:

```
#include "MathFunctions.h"

double median(double values[], int count) {
    int i, j, n = count, t;
    for (i = 1 ; i <= n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1 ; j <= n - i ; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] <= values[j + 1])
            {
                t = (int) values[j];
                values[j] = values[j + 1];
                values[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( n % 2 == 0)
        return (values[n / 2] + values[n / 2 + 1]) / 2.0 ;
    else
        return values[n / 2 + 1];
}
```

I'm a beginner in C++ and I don't understand why this is working like that. I'd rather expect it to put declarations of methods like:

```
double median(double values[], int count);
```

In *.h file and the interior of the method in *.cpp file and then include the *.h file in my main.cpp like that:

```
#include "MathFunctions.h"
```

Can someone explain me why this is working like that? What am I supposed to do with the files created by CLion? Should I include MathFunctions.cpp instead of header file in my main.cpp?

Comment: I don't use CLion, but to confirm what you are expecting I would expect as well. The define is nice but the #include "MathFunctions.h" should be inside that define.  Don't include the *.cpp file in the main since that would break data encapsulation, any private functions in that file also becomes call able.

Comment: So why is it so much broken? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a CLion bug, tracked by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9329, please create a Jetbrains account and vote for this issue.

I am not sure what you mean by "workaround". To make your code working, you need to

1. Create the function declaration for `double median(double values[], int count);` in the `MathFunctions.h` include file.
2. In your `main.cpp`, add `#include "MathFunctions.h` as you mention
3. In CMakeLists.txt (and this is not CLion specific, you need to know the basics of CMake), add file `MathFunctions.cpp` to the list of source files for your executable.

For example, assuming you have a CLion-created CMakeLists.txt, you should have something similar to

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp MathFunctions.cpp)
add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Some other random comments:

- `median()` is not a "method", it is a "function", or more precisely a "free-standing function" (that is, a function that is not part of a class).
- `median()` is not really C++, is C, since it uses a low-level C array. You may want to use a `std::vector<double>` instead.
- C and C++ are low-level and, depending from which languages you are coming from, can be confusing :-) I suggest picking a good, recent book on *modern* C++. Modern C++ refers to at least C++11 and a style of programming where you almost never perform *direct* memory allocation/deallocation (that is, you don't use `new` and `delete`). Good luck in your journey!

**Edit**

Changed link to Jetbrains bug to the first one reporting the issue.

Comment: I see your issue was marked as duplicate. So I voted on the other one here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9329 and I encourage everyone to do the same. I'm really disappointed that such elementary function can be broken in such a great IDE. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @Defozo updated link to point to the original issue, thanks for noticing.